# add_filter( 'user_has_cap','my_function', 10, 3 ); and call to get_users in my function triggers an infinite loop in user list

Tags: filters, user-meta

I use:

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap','my_function', 10, 3 );
```

In user list to allow users to edit only a specific list of users with a meta user identical to a current user connected.

To get the list of users I use `get_users($args);` but this triggers an infinite loop.

I guess somewhere `get_users` calls `user_has_cap` again.

I try to remove_filter before `get_users($args);`, this works but the filter only works the first time in my user list.

I try to add `add_filter( 'user_has_cap','my_function', 10, 3 );` after `get_users($args);` but again this triggers an infinite loop.

```
remove_filter( 'user_has_cap', __FUNCTION__ );
$user_ids = get_users($args);
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'author_cap_filter', 10, 3 );
```

My other solution is to write a SQL query with `$wpdb->get_results`.

Comment: Have you tried `remove_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'my_function', 10 );` (rather than using `__FUNCTION__`)?

Comment: It's the same, you can write 'author_cap_filter' it's name of my function or the magic constant  __FUNCTION__ in php. At the and i use $wpdb to write a sql query

Comment: if it's the same then it should be written the same, but make the change anyway just to rule out that it isn't the cause. Remember just because something _should_ be the same, doesn't mean it is. Likewise your `remove_filter` call does not have a priority or arg count